# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java, netbeans, solr

Below code is for "Search using SolrJ".
When running code this error is shown.

IDE is netbean.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
**HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");**

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("sony digital camera");
query.addFilterQuery("cat:electronics","store:amazon.com");
query.setFields("id","price","merchant","cat","store");
query.setStart(0);    
query.set("defType", "edismax");

QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
  System.out.println(results.get(i));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException

You are missing NoHttpResponseException class in your classpath while running the code. To resolve this, just add apache `httpcore-4.0.1.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: I have httpcore-4.1.4 and httpcore-4.1.3 in library and added them to netbean

Comment: i deleted one this library and problem is solved. but other error is shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have" and "added them"?

Comment: Excuse me. my English is not good. I mean that this library existed and i had added them to IDE.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you are either missing the httpcore-4.0.jar or have an old version of it, since it used on 4.0 and after.

Also check if you have it in the deployment path.